# Java method for recursive matrix multiply?

Tags: java, arrays, return, dimensional

So basically, what I want to do is make a method that takes 2 matrices as arguments, and multiplies them. This is a school task, and Im asked to solve this by using recursive "Divide and Conquer". This is my code so far:

```
public class RecMult {

    public int[][] calc(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

        int n = a.length;
        int[][] c = new int[n][n];

        if (n == 1) {
            c[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0];
        } else {
            int sub = a.length / 2;
            int[][] smalla11 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla12 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla21 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smalla22 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb11 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb12 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb21 = new int[sub][sub];
            int[][] smallb22 = new int[sub][sub];

            for (int i = 0; i < sub; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < sub; j++) {
                    smalla11[i][j] = a[i][j];
                    smalla12[sub + i][j] = a[sub + i][j];
                    smalla21[i][sub + j] = a[i][sub + j];
                    smalla22[sub + i][sub + j] = a[sub + i][sub + j];
                    smallb11[i][j] = b[i][j];
                    smallb12[sub + i][j] = b[sub + i][j];
                    smallb21[i][sub + j] = b[i][sub + j];
                    smallb22[sub + i][sub + j] = b[sub + i][sub + j];
                }
            }
            c[0][0] = calc(smalla11, smallb11);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

I did not complete the code because I encountered a problem pretty fast. I'm not able to set `c[0][0]` to `calc(smalla11, smallb11)` because it takes an int, and the `calc` method returns a int[][]. Im not actually sure what to do at this point. Sometimes, I would have wanted to return just a single int, but later I would want to return submatrices and at last the full matrix. Does anyone have any suggestions, either on how to "fix" this return issue, or maybe even a better idea on how to write the code for such a program?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store a 2 dimensional array (the results from calc(smalla11, smallb11)) into a single element c[0,0].  c has already been declared to be a 2 dimensional array.  Are you intentionally trying to store the result in a single point 0,0?

Would this do what you need?

```
c =  calc(smalla11, smallb11);
```

This makes my brain hurt, but it's fun! :)

Comment: Im aware of that, and I tried to say so too :p The thing is, and as far as I know, this code (which I got as a pseudocode) works with itself until its just 1 int to multiply with another. At this point, the code is just returning an int. BUT its recursive, and from now on, it should return a c int[sub][sub] until it in the end returns c[n][n] where n is the maximum length of the dimension of the array. The arrays are n x n btw. Im kinda confused on how to get all this into one working recursive method, but as far as I know, I have to use another one, unless I declare the int in another way.